# Using dynamic SQL to Create Table with today’s date as the table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I am attempting to create a table where the name of the table is todays date and the time of day in the format 2023-11-06-12-10.
My code looked like this and errored with the message "Incorrect syntax near '2023'".

```
DECLARE @MyTableName sysname;
DECLARE @DynamicSQL nvarchar(max);
SET @MyTableName = FORMAT (GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm');
SET @DynamicSQL = N'CREATE TABLE ' + @MyTableName + ' (DocIDNo varchar(255))';
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQL;
```

I changed the `SET @MyTableName` to this

```
SET @MyTableName = 'House'
```

and this worked :) I then tried

```
SET @MyTableName = '2023'
```

and got the same error "Incorrect syntax near '2023'"

Comment: why do you want to create tables with dates in names. better have a column called `Date` that you populate and name table something normal. If you wanna do it, the syntax is: `CREATE TABLE [Some complex name with spaces or numbers]`

Comment: Yes, well it's expecting a table name but it's getting the mathematical expression `2023 - 11 - 06 - 12 - 10`. This seems like a design issue but have you tried using `QUOTENAME(@MyTableName)` instead?

Comment: That is what the end user has requested To enable them to import into the next system?

Comment: Object names are names, don't put data into names. Push back on the end user, this is flat wrong.

Comment: This is very bad, terrible practice. Don't put data into table names, and don't start table names with numbers. Creating a new table every day for the same data and with a different table name is also very much not recommended. This seems like a case of the end user not understanding what they need vs. what they want. Maybe a daily flat file export would do the same, and wouldn't cause your dba to have an aneurysm.

Answer (score 0):

As `@AlwaysLearning` mentioned you can try using the `QUOTENAME` function to ensure that the table name is properly quoted and any special characters are handled correctly:

```sql
DECLARE @MyTableName sysname;
DECLARE @DynamicSQL nvarchar(max);
SET @MyTableName = REPLACE(FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm'), ' ', '_');
SET @DynamicSQL = N'CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@MyTableName) + ' (DocIDNo varchar(255))';
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQL;
```